# Error when installing Terraform Err:5 404 Not Found

Tags: terraform, linux-mint

I am using LMDE 4 Debbie and I am trying to install Terraform on my laptop

I am following steps defined in https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/install-cli

And when I run `sudo apt updated` I am getting the following error

```
 Err:5 https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com debbie Release                                                                                                                
  404  Not Found [IP: 2a04:4e42:25::561 443]
```

and also when I try to install it says not found

```
$ sudo apt install terraform
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package terraform
```

Comment: Sadly your question is not clear. What linux are you using exactly? What version? There are many versions of linux mint.

Comment: LMDE 4 Debbie, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`debbie` is likely the return of `lsb_release -cs`, and you need to replace that with a valid Debian distribution to subscribe to an existing apt repo. LMDE 4 is based on `buster`, so you can use the command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt.releases.hashicorp.com buster main"
```

instead of the return of `lsb_release -cs` for the distro. That should fix your issue.